# Evaluate $\int_L{\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

How can I evaluate $$\int_L{\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}$$, where:

L: 
$$x=\cos{t};$$
$$y=a\cdot\sin{t};$$
$$z=a\cdot t$$ 
$$0\leq t \leq 2\pi$$

So far I tried it this way:

$$I=\int_L{\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2}}ds=\int_0^{2\pi}{(\frac{a^2t^2}{\cos^2{t}+a^2\cdot\sin^2{t}}\sqrt{(\frac{d(\cos{t})}{dt})^2 + (\frac{d(a\cdot \sin{t})}{dt})^2 +(\frac{d(a\cdot t)}{dt})^2}})dt=\int_0^{2\pi}{(\frac{a^2t^2}{\cos^2{t}+a^2\cdot\sin^2{t}}\sqrt{\sin^2{t} + a^2\cdot\cos^2{t} +a^2}})dt$$

and that is where I am getting stuck as I can't reduce of simplify this expression.
How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Are you sure $x=\cos t$ and not $x=a\cos t$ (or maybe just $y=\sin t$)?

Comment: Yes, that is the nature of this problem, either someone has excluded the $a$ out by mistake or this is intended.